# Trouble with running Server-Client c program on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: c, macos, sockets, unix

I just start to learn UNIX network programming with c, and made a small TCP Server-Client program.

It runs perfect on Fedora, but have some connection issues on my MacBook.

Compiling can be done in terminal with no problem, but after I ran the "server" program then ran the "client" program, It seems like "server" didn't get the "connect" command from the "client". Codes and msgs are like below:

server.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MYPORT 1500
#define BACKLOG 5
#define MAXDATASIZE 100

int main()
{
    int servSock, cliProc;
    socklen_t sin_size;
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE], msg[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr, income_addr;

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if ((servSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        printf("Socket Error: %d\n", errno);
    else
        printf("Server Socket %d created\n", servSock);

    if (bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
        printf("Bind Error: %d\n", errno);
    else
        printf("Server Bind created\n");

    listen(servSock, BACKLOG);
    printf("Server is waitting for connection...\n");

    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if ((cliProc = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *)&income_addr, &sin_size)) == -1)
        printf("Accept Error: %d\n", errno);
    else
    {
        printf("Server accepted connection from %s\n", inet_ntoa(income_addr.sin_addr));
    }

    sprintf(msg, "Welcome to Server, you addr is %s", inet_ntoa(income_addr.sin_addr));
    send(cliProc, msg, strlen(msg), 0);

    if (recv(cliProc, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0) == -1)
    {
        printf("Recv Error: %d\n", errno);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Server received %s from %s\n", buf, inet_ntoa(income_addr.sin_addr));
    }

    close(cliProc);
    close(servSock);
    printf("Server Sockets closed\n");

    return 0;
}
```

client.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXDATASIZE 100
#define PORT 1500

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int cliSock, numbytes;
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE], msg[MAXDATASIZE];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("%d, Usage: Client Hostname\n", argc);
        exit(1);
    }

    struct hostent *he;

    if ((he = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't get hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;

    dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    dest_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);

    if ((cliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        printf("Socket Error: %d\n", errno);
    else
        printf("Client Socket %d created\n", cliSock);

    if (connect(cliSock, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == 1)
        printf("Connect Error: %d\n", errno);
    else
    {
        printf("Client Connection created\n");
    }

    numbytes = recv(cliSock, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0);
    buf[numbytes] = '\0';
    printf("Received Message: %s\n", buf);

    sprintf(msg, "4 8 15 16 23 42");
    send(cliSock, msg, MAXDATASIZE, 0);
    printf("Client sent %s to %s\n", msg, inet_ntoa(dest_addr.sin_addr));

    close(cliSock);
    printf("Client Sockets closed\n");

    return 0;
}
```

server msg:

```
Server Socket 3 created
Server Bind created
Server is waitting for connection...
```

client msg:

```
Client Socket 3 created
Client Connection created
Received Message:
```

Any help will be thankful. :)

Comment: Try to temporary shutdown firewall as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a)** On your server, add a verification to check whether `listen` did succeed or not. It's likely to be failing. You can find out the cause with:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

**b)** On your client, the condition below is checking against the wrong value. It should check for `!= 0`.  Quoting [connect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect): `If the connection or binding succeeds, zero is returned. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.`.

```
if (connect(cliSock,(struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == 1)
    printf("Connect Error: %d\n", errno);
else
    printf("Client Connection created\n");
```

**c)** In cases like yours, I generally recommend testing the connection with a client that is known to work, such as `telnet` or [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/). This helps reducing the verification area. If the connection doesn't succeed, the problem is in your server. Otherwise, it's a problem with your client. Of course, you could still have problems in both, but you need to fix one bug at a time.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help, i did checked worry value at "connect()", after i corrected that part, it showed the "errno" is 61, which means that "the client machine can't connect to the ip/port i'm trying to connect to on the server", so i tried to connect directly with "127.0.0.1", then everything worked fine. So the real problem is something about the DNS part, it turned out that the result of "gethostbyname()" is a public IP address instead of a local IP address. Now i think i will just use the local IP address to do the test. Thanks again and have a good day! :)